# Como usar metodo reset() CaptchaModule primeng Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, captcha

solicito de su ayuda debido a que tengo problemas con el componente CaptchaModule debido a que refresco hago un envió la pagina y me sale lo siguiente `Recaptcha is not loaded`

**Html**

```
<p-captcha [siteKey]="llave (onResponse)="showResponse($event)">
</p-captcha>
```

**Ts**

```
showResponse ( event ) {
  console.log ( "Evento: ", event.response );
}
```

Comment: Quité la etiqueta [tag:google-apps-script] pues no tiene relación con dicha plataforma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en tu HTML, no cierras bien la propiedad `[siteKey]` y así no se logra ejecutar nunca el evento `(onResponse)`

```
<p-captcha [siteKey]="llave (onResponse)="showResponse($event)"></p-captcha>
```

---

También te recomiendo que utilices el DOM de tu componente 'captcha' para verificar que estes enviando una siteKey en respuesta a tu metodo

**HTML :**

```
<p-captcha #captcha [siteKey]="llave" (onResponse)="showResponse($event)"></p-captcha>
```

**TS :**

```
@ViewChild('captcha') cap;

constructor() { }

showResponse(event) {
  console.log("Propiedad", this.cap.siteKey);
  console.log("Evento: ", JSON.stringify(event.response));
  // 
  this.cap.reset();
}
```